# npm not installing file system module dependencies correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

Suppose that I have a file system node module Module1 with its package.json (located in tha path /module1)

```
{
   "devDependencies": {
    "A": "^1.0.0",
    "B": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "A": "^1.0.0",
    "B": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

And another module Module2 that uses this file system module as dependency with package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "Module1": "file:/module1"
  }

"devDependencies": {
    "Module1": "file:/module1"
  }
```

When I install the second module with `npm install` I see that in its folder `node_modules` are not present the dependencies A, B of Module1.

If I add those dependencies inside the package.json of Module2

```
"dependencies": {
    "A": "^1.0.0",
    "B": "^1.0.0"
    "Module1": "file:/module1"
  }

"devDependencies": {
    "A": "^1.0.0",
    "B": "^1.0.0"
    "Module1": "file:/module1"
  }
```

however when I import Module1 from Module2 it is not able to find them and it triggers an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'A'
```

I can solve this problem by installing the dependencies of Module1 inside its own folder `/module1` with `npm install`. However I'm wondering if there is another way to achieve the same result only installing the dependencies of Module2

Comment: If you want to link one local package to another you should use `npm link`, see docs

Comment: @Dimava Thanks for your comment. Just a simple question: before linking to I need to install ModuleA dependencies through npm install?

Comment: Doensn't matter

Comment: @Dimava and the dependencies of Module1 are solved during the installation of Module2? Thanks again